# I rendered the png sequence but the result video is jittery!

Tags: rendering, video

I rendered my frames as png, and then imported in Premere Pro, but the video is playing jittery.

My friend changed blender frame rate to 30, is that the problem?

images are HD but video is not clear:

https://youtu.be/-97o-jyDDnY

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Blender video editing mode for exporting videos.
[image: Step 1]

Then press Shift-A to get drop down add-file menu, or click on the "Add" button.[image]
(Sorry about the sloppy arrow. I didn't have enough time to draw a good one)
select the "Image" button and go to the file in the file browser that you want to add frames from, and press A to select all. If you only want to select certain frames, then you can shift click on a frame to select it too.[image]
Now you need to go to the box labeled "Add image strip" in the bottom left corner, and set the frame start/stop to the amount of frames you want to import.[image]
Now select add image strip in the top right corner.
Now you can select the output format like you would normal renders, but instead of exporting as png, you export the animation as a video format. Whatever works for you. Once it is done creating the video, you can watch it in the location you set it to render to. This is Blender's Sequence rendering mode, which is probably best for quick Blender animation videos.

Comment: thanks it also helps a little, but I think my camera was moving very fast so that jittery look might be inevitable.

Comment: Yes. That was probably the case. If you want, you can re-render the animation at 60 frames a second. That should make the movie smooth.